# How to obtain transformation parameters between the Vertical Reference System EGM-96 and a Local Geoid Model?

Tags: datasets, aeronautical-charts, aeronautical-information

Dear Mr/Mrs Geodesy Engineer, Cartographers and AIS Specialists

I have a quite deep question here,
AIP data locations are determined by geographic coordinates /X & Y axis/ and vertical values /Z axis/ via Geodesy science.

ICAO adopted EGM-96 standard for Vertical Reference System.

Question is raised regarding to Annex-15, 1.2.2.3:

> ....When a geoid model other than the EGM-96 model is used, a
>   description of the model used, including the parameters required for
>   height transformation between the model and EGM-96, shall be provided
>   in the Aeronautical Information Publication (AIP).

In Mongolia, we are not using EGM-96 for Vertical Reference System. Instead, wWe are using the Baltic sea level value /1940-1970/ in Air Navigation.

My question is: How to figure out the parameters required for height transformation between any model and EGM-96 for AIP publication?
In my thinking, the parameters must contain following values: ∆X, ∆ Y, ∆ Z, X rotation, Y rotation, Z rotation, Scale... etc. Is this correct?

Comment: Interesting question, and I think it is on topic. However, I would expect this question will get better answers at https://gis.stackexchange.com/,

Comment: The few thousand different projections that exist and transforming between them is a problem GIS professionals deal a lot more frequently than pilots. As @DeltaLima has suggested, you're much more likely to get a good answer at gis.stackexchange.com.